# Crossfade between images in Android

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, porter-duff

I am working on an Android application at the moment.  I do all my drawing onto a Canvas object using predominantly the drawBitmap method.  The current effect I am trying to achieve is to "cross-fade" between two Bitmaps.  The two bitmaps are similar images, with only the outer part different.  By crossfading, the inner parts that are identical should remain the same, while the outer regions seem to fade from one state to another.  I looked at each of the PorterDuff.Modes that are available, but none fit the exact effect I want.  Basically I think the equation I am looking to implement is:

w = weight (from 0 to 1)
a_i, c_i = alpha and color values for image i = 1 and 2

(a1, c1) +(w) (a2, c2) = ((1-w)*a1 + w*a2, ((1-w)*a1*c1 + w*a2*c2) / ((1-w)*a1 + w*a2))

(of course, accounting for zero-divide cases as well - this is basically a weighted "averaging" of the two images)

Is there any way to go about writing a "custom" PorterDuff mode to implement this?  I don't want to have to extract the color arrays of each Bitmap and manually loop through them at each frame to do this transformation if there is a more efficient way to implement this.

If anyone knows a way to go about this efficiently, or knows of another method I am unaware of and couldn't find online, that would be very appreciated.  Also, if my transformation seems to be inappropriate for this task, your criticism would also be welcome.

P.S.  I tried to interpolate just the alpha values and draw both images as-is, but for instance in the middle of the interpolation, both have alpha values of 0.5 in regions where it is normally 1, and drawing two 0.5 alpha images results in transparency, which is not what I want.  A normal ADD operation should end up saturating the colors, which is also not desired.